# What does STL method sort() do if I have equal elements in a data structure?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

If I sort for example a data structure of integers, I know that the STL method sort() sorts the integers low to high, but what if in my data structures I've got equals integers? What does STL sort do? Is  STL sort() keeping by default the order of the equal values that are in the data structure?

Comment: [STL `sort`](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/sort.html) is documented to not be stable. Descriptions of [standard library `sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) likewise state that "The order of equal elements is not guaranteed to be preserved."

Answer (score 12):

It is unspecified. If you want to preserve ordering of equivalent elements, use [`std::stable_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort).